# TextView value to change

Tags: java, android

im new to android development. Im trying to create two screens, the first one display name, surname, ect. The second screen is to update the information in the textview fields on the first screen. I have created the readToFile method and the readFromFile method. How do I change the data that is displayed on the first screen when I click the save button on the second screen? When the first screen opens the textviews is set to display something allready. When I want to set the text to display the new info it doesnt change.

Comment: could you share your code ?

Answer (score 0):

[Intents](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) can help you with that. When you move from one screen to another, you can pass on the data from the EditTexts to the next screen and then read the data in onCreate() of next screen. [This](https://www.101apps.co.za/articles/passing-data-between-activities.html) tutorial can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

When you press save button, set isDataChanged variable to true.

Override the `onBackPressed` method in Second Activity and finish the `Activity` with resultCode. In First Activity, override the `onActivityResult` method and call readFromFile.

In Second Activity,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
   if (isDataChanged) {
      setResult(1);
      ActivityCompat.finishAfterTransition(this);
    }
}
```

In First Activity

```
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == 1) {
        updateList(data);

    }
```

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

pass the value between activities through intent and set the data accordingly